# Run a view's bulk operation immediately but in background. Is that possible?

Tags: views, actions

Is it possible to run a view's bulk operation immediately after pressing the button but in the background (in other words, without forcing the user to wait until the progress bar completes to 100%)?

I understand that this can be achieved by enqueuing the operation. But the problem of this solution is that execution is postponed until cron is run.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP needs something to drive the process, it's not multi-threaded. Drupal's queue process runs by either the client's browser making a series of calls (kind of like it emulates the cron), or by the cron itself.

Why isn't the cron an acceptable method? You can use something like [ultimate_cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) The control the schedule for each cron tasks.

### Update

As @Molot mentioned, the CLI is an option. I believe `shell_exec` is subject to PHP's timeout (I could be wrong). [See this blog post](http://www.davenewson.com/dev/methods-for-asynchronous-processes-in-php) on executing PHP in an asynchronous fashion.

Comment: Actually, your answer is "no", but in reality it is, indeed, possible. Maybe not coded for VBO, but it may be possible to run PHP CLI app for the job. Or, way more directly, you can open batch processing in a pop-under window. So the user does not need to wait for the bar to get to 100% to do something else. There are many ways.

Comment: Curious why you've downvoted this answer? Because it's different than yours?

Comment: Curious how you assume you know who downvoted? Because I explained why your answer isn't exactly true?

Comment: I did assume it was you. I apologize if I'm wrong. I stated how VBO batch processes works, my answer isn't wrong.

Comment: I like your idea of using the CLI.